# I have 3 cells I only want info in 1 of the 3 cells and the other 2 blank(empty)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 cells B13, C13, D13 I only want data in 1 of the 3 cells and the other 2 Blank

1 of the 3 cells should have "XX" in it and the other 2 empty

How would you write this VB code?

and then where would you place it?

[image: example image]

Comment: Formula would not do this, one would need to use VBA in a Worksheet_Change event to automatically clear the other two upon entry in one.  One can also use DataValidation to make the user clear the other two prior to entering a value in the other one.

Comment: Hey @James S.,, you may try Data Validation for CUSTOM use this one `=COUNTA($B$13:$D$13)<=1`, this will allow only one value at a time to enter in range `B13:D13`,, Or if you want to accept only `XX` in any of the cells then use,,  `=AND(EXACT(B13,"XX"),COUNTA(B13:D13)<=1)` ☺

Answer (score 0):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B13:D13")

    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case Target.Address(o, o)
            Case "B13"
                Range("C13:D13").ClearContents
            Case "D13"
                Range("B13:C13").ClearContents
            Case "C13"
                Range("B13").ClearContents
                Range("D13").ClearContents
        End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**